# Why is a constexpr value captured by this lambda not constexpr?

Tags: c++, lambda, constexpr

I want to pass a constexpr integer to a function, so I have declared a type for this purpose, ConstExprInt.  This works well in most cases, except when I try to nest it within two lambdas. I've edited this question to fix some obvious problems.

```
template <int N>
struct ConstExprInt
{
    constexpr operator int () const { return N; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ConstExprInt <1> One;

    static_assert(One == 1);    // is okay, value of One is constexpr

    auto lambda1 = [&]() {
        static_assert(One == 1); // is okay, captured value is constexpr
    };

    lambda1();
    
    auto lambda2 = [&](auto Passed)
    {
        static_assert(Passed == 1); // is okay, passed value is constexpr
        
        auto lambda3 = [&]() {
            static_assert(Passed == 1, "compilation fails"); // compilation fails! not constexpr!
        };
        
        lambda3();
    };

    lambda2(One);
}
```

Compilation fails only in the last case, and only before C++17:

```
$ g++-9 -std=c++14 test31.cpp -o test31
test31.cpp: In instantiation of ‘main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:1)> [with auto:1 = ConstExprInt<1>]’:
test31.cpp:30:16:   required from here
test31.cpp:24:34: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
   24 |             static_assert(Passed == 1, "compilation fails"); // compilation fails: captured value is not constexpr
      |                           ~~~~~~~^~~~
test31.cpp:24:34: error: use of ‘this’ in a constant expression
$ g++-9 -std=c++17 test31.cpp -o test31
$ # (no errors)
```

Why does this not compile under C++14?

Comment: gcc 11 (godbolt) accepts the posted code , even in c++14 mode , so perhaps it is a compiler bug that has been fixed